# Firebreath MethodConverter.h invalid initialization

Tags: objective-c, firebreath

Hi I created a firebreath project. I added this methods to the default generated code:

In the application API header file (MYAppAPI.h):

```
FB_JSAPI_EVENT(bgp, 3, (const FB::variant&, bool, int));

std::string bgp(std::string& val);
```

In the application API source file (MAppAPI.mm I am using objective-c):

```
registerMethod("bgp", make_method(this, &MyAppAPI::bgp));

std::string MyAppAPI::bgp(std::string& val){...}
```

But when I build the code, I am getting this error:

...firebreath/src/ScriptingCore/MethodConverter.h:115: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string&' from a temporary of type 'std::basic_string, std::allocator >'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should read:

```
std::string MyAppAPI::bgp(const std::string& val){...}
```

note the const.  You can't pass things by reference into a JS function, so it won't let you pass a non-const reference.